# Lost message in RabbitMQ

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqplib

i'm implemented a simple message service with rabbitMq and videlalvaro/php-amqplib php client. But when I send two messages my receiver loses one. any idea what could have happened? The code used is below.

send.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$connection = new AMQPConnection('127.0.0.1', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);

for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $text = "SEND MESSAGE ".$i;

    $msg = new AMQPMessage($text);
    $channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');

    echo " [x] SEND MESSAGE ".$i."\n";  
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

receiver.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection;

$connection = new AMQPConnection('127.0.0.1', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);
echo ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C', "\n";

$callback = function($msg) {
  echo " [x] Received: ", $msg->body, "\n";
};

$channel->basic_consume('hello', '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

send.php print response

[x] SEND MESSAGE 0 
[x] SEND MESSAGE 1 
[x] SEND MESSAGE 2 
[x] SEND MESSAGE 3 
[x] SEND MESSAGE 4 
[x] SEND MESSAGE 5 
[x] SEND MESSAGE 6 
[x] SEND MESSAGE 7 
[x] SEND MESSAGE 8 
[x] SEND MESSAGE 9

receiver.php print response

[x] Received: SEND MESSAGE 1 
[x] Received: SEND MESSAGE 3 
[x] Received: SEND MESSAGE 5 
[x] Received: SEND MESSAGE 7 
[x] Received: SEND MESSAGE 9

Comment: I have only receiver.php

Comment: check your subscribers, you have two consumers the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Had same troubles and lost much time searching the solution. Finally it was a deficiency of free space on the disk where Rabbit Server was installed. It said "50mb watermark", but somehow troubles starts under 1GB free space. Messages are going somewhere.

And try to red server logs, maybe you'll find the hint.